# Moving from DatePicker range to DateTimePicker range?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've managed to implement a DatePicker element with the "range" type as seen [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker) (select the Range radio), however I'm trying to switch over to DateTimePicker and don't know how to keep this layout and format.

I want the calendar to show when the user clicks on the input field -- not interested in a button like they show [here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php). However, whenever I remove the `<span>` element for that button the whole thing breaks, not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" />
```

JS:

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    //language:  'fr',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    showMeridian: 1
});
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a range-type input for the DateTimePicker, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've seen is to link two of them together like this.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                useCurrent: false 
            });
            $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
            $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Check out
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers
It's where I got it from and it works for me.